# Why is Tex is not rendering in the right way on math stackexchange?

Tags: 16.04, fonts

Why is Tex is not rendering in the right way on math stackexchange ?
[image]

Also I have set all fonts helvetica using unity tweak tool. Still I am viewing google in ubuntu font. I have also changed web browser font to helvetica.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematics Stack Exchange built-in editor uses [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) to render LaTeX. MathJax is an open-source JavaScript engine that makes it easy to embed mathematical equations, symbols, and formulae on a webpage. [MathJax documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/start.html)

Mathematics Stack Exchange Markdown Editor Help can be accessed by clicking the *edit* link under a post followed by *advanced help »* or by going to the [LaTeX Markdown Editor Help — Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) webpage.

Please note the use of the single dollar sign to delimit inline equations instead of the double dollar sign to delimit blocks in this example.

```
integral of $\int\sin3x\cos3x \mathop{\mathrm{d}x}$
```

[image: IMG:]

It is also possible to edit MathJax markdown text locally by installing Typora markdown editor in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu.

```
sudo snap install typora-alanzanattadev
```

[image]

Comment: Can you notice the slight change in font for your and my tex fonts ?

Comment: Yes, I notice there is a difference in the two fonts. My font came from a screenshot I made from a post at the Mathematics Stack Exchange website. Do you want my results to be displayed in a different font? Maybe I can change it by changing the default font in my Firefox (serif), otherwise I used the default font that was shown in Firefox when I visited Mathematics Stack Exchange.